# Is there a way to do complex long division?

Tags: complex-analysis

So I know that $z^2+z+1-i$ can be factored out as $(z-i)(z+i+1)$. Now if you were only given one of its factors, is there a way to figure out the other factor using complex long division? I tried it and it doesn't seem possible like polynomial long division.

Comment: Polynomial long division works the same way over any field. It's a bit more annoying over the complex numbers because you have to do complex divisions but it's the same structurally.

Comment: Yes you can do it. It is exactly the same as polynomial long division, just keep in mind that the coefficient can be complex

Comment: Suppose we divide it by $z-i$. We subtract $z^2-iz$ so $(1+i)z + (1-i)$ remain. But $(1+i)z + (1-i) = (1+i)(z-i)$.

Comment: "it doesn't seem possible like polynomial long division": why not ?

Answer (score 1):

It works completly fine. For example:

$(z^2+z+1-i)\div (z-i)=\color{red}{z}+\color{blue}{i+1}$

First step:
$z^2\div z=\color{red}{z}$

and $z(z-i)=z^2-iz$.
Then $z^2+z+1-i-(z^2-iz)=(i+1)z+(1-i)$

Second step:
Now $(i+1)z\div z=\color{blue}{i+1}$

and $(z-i)(i+1)=(i+1)z+1-i$.
Then $(i+1)z+(1-i)-((i+1)z+1-i)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

By long division,

$$z^2+az+b=(z+a-c)(z+c)+(b-ac+c^2).$$

This identity is true in any commutative field.

(Obviously if $z+c$ is known to be a factor, then $z^2+az+b=(z+a-c)(z+c)$.)

Answer (score 0):

Since the divisor is of degree one, you could also use synthetic division:

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
i & 1 & 1 & 1-i \\
& & i & i-1\\
\hline
& 1 & 1+i & 0 \\
\end{array}
$$